# Is there any free host which supports PHP with curl enabled?

Tags: looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for a web host which supports PHP with CURL extension enabled. I tried a few of them but they keep showing me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [FreeHostia's Chocolate plan](http://www.freehostia.com/free-chocolate.html). They appear to have cURL enabled for PHP.

Comment: Thanx and I'll check it out.